# How is the following relation involving modulo operation equal?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Why does the following equation hold?
$$\frac{2^{lk}-1}{2^l-1}\bmod p=(2^{lk}-1)(2^l-1)^{p-2} \bmod p,$$
where $p=100000007$

That is (in more standard mathematical notation),
$$\frac{2^{lk}-1}{2^l-1}\equiv (2^{lk}-1)(2^l-1)^{p-2} \pmod p$$
Does this equality depend upon value of p?

Comment: It depends on the fact that $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it ends up, $p$ is a prime number.  For any prime number, [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) tells us that

> for any prime $p$, and for any $a$ for which $a\neq 0 \pmod p$: $$a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$$

In this context, that means that
$(2^l-1)^{p-1}\equiv 1$, as long as $2^l-1$ is not a multiple of $p$.  It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
(2^{lk}-1)/(2^l-1) &\equiv (2^{lk}-1)/(2^l-1) * 1 \pmod p\\
&\equiv (2^{lk}-1)/(2^l-1) * (2^l-1)^{p-1} \pmod p\\
&\equiv (2^{lk}-1)(2^l-1)^{p-2} \pmod p
\end{align}
$$

So to directly answer your question: yes, the answer does depend on what $p$ is.  This theorem will work for any prime $p$ and the right choice of $l$, but those aren't the only situations where this equality will happen to hold.

Comment: As long, as $p\nmid 2^l-1$, otherwise the expression is not even well-defined. For instance, take $l=0$. (More generally, $p\mid 2^l-1$, iff $ord_{\mathbb Z_p^*}(2)\mid l$)